# Remote GPIO transfer protocol

Tags: pigpio

Wondering about host to host security concerns when using Remote GPIO (with pigpio).

An open port is very likely to be insecure, I understand that.

After googling there are some questions that I can't find the answer to:

Is the link between the local and remote host secure?

Can the command messages be sniffed? If not encrypted you could reverse-engineer the protocol if you are capable of (probably I'm not).

I have a few watering systems commanded by a couple or raspberry pi and remote gpio would be a great idea. One script to rule them all!

Comment: related: https://github.com/gpiozero/gpiozero/issues/434 though I leave an authoritative answer to joan.

Comment: It is an open protocol http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html. It is local LAN only (nobody would be stupid enough to open the pigpiod port (8888) to the public internet). There are some rudimentary controls for IP address filtering. There's no openSSL encryption.  http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote pigpio is not secure.  There is no encryption between the daemon and the outside.

If you need a secure link you will have to find an alternative solution.